# google OAuth for service on unusual port

Tags: oauth, https, timeout, port, google-oauth

I have running my own website for security reasons at an unusual port: https on Port 11223 instead oh 443.

This website provides the feature to login with an google account, realized by using the google OAuth API.

At the last step of authentication (redirecting back from google OAuth to my system), an network timeout happens.

On the other hand: if my server is running https on default port 443 instead of 11223, everything works fine.

I have configured the google OAuth client settings (Redirect URIs, Home page URL, JavaScript origins) for using the special port 112233. But without success.

Maybe it's important to know, the Server is behind a firewall with NAT. This means, the firewall receives https connections to port 11223 to redirect this to the internal webserver running https only on port 11223. But I think, this is not the point.

What could be the reason, why port 443 works but port 11223 doesn't. 
I guess google OAuth does not support webservers running on an unusual prot!?!

Answer (score 2):

The port number is 16 bits and thus can not exceed 65535.

Comment: yes, you are right. But in this case, this was a typo in order to avoid posting the real setting. I changed my question.

Comment: By saying 'the last step of authentication', did your browser receive any response from Google after you click the 'Allow access' button? The question is where did the timeout happen - between the browser and Google OAuth2 server, or between the browser and your site server?

Comment: the timeout happens between the browser and my site. And it works, if my server runs on port 443, the default ssl port, instead of 11223. google did an redirect and probably google ignores the specific port. So it looks like google redirects to 443 instead of 11223, even I have configured 11223 at the google API interface/setting.

Comment: You may capture the http 302 response from Google to see whether google redirect to port 11223. You may also try pointing your browser to https://your-server:11223 to see whether your server does receive the request on port 11223.

Comment: Also, note that Google supports multiple redirect_uri for the same application. So you need to specify the port in the redirect_uri in the request.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be proxy configuration issues? I recommend you configure your firewall to return 404 on the port 11223 and see what happens.

Comment: Hi breno. There is no proxy in use. The firewall only does NAT to the server insight. The firewall I use is only a port filter without the feature to return/redirect an 404 page on an specific port. The firewall works on an lower level than a proxy.